# Changing color of some text in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a JLabel with text in it, and I want to append another piece of text to it, but the latter will be of a different color than the former (e.g. red). I've tried:

```
statusLabel.setText(statusLabel.getText() +
  " <html><span style\"color: red\">" + message + "</span></html>");
```

But it doesn't work. It just shows the HTML tags but does not render them. Any suggestions? Is it possible to change the color of some of the text in a JLabel?

Comment: Have you tried `label.setForeground()`?

Comment: That method changes the color of all of the text in the label. I only want a couple of words to be in a different color.

Comment: What about `setText("<html>" + statusLabel.getText() + "<font color=\"red\">" + message + "</font></html>")`?

Comment: I guess you forgot to add `=` after style, moreover no quotes are required around `'color: red'`. On my side this thing works fine `<html><body><p><span style = color:RED >Select</span> One Colour : </p></body></html>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
setText("<html>Some text <font color='red'>some text in red</font></html>");
```

Or for you case you can build the string like this:

```
statusLabel.setText(String.format("<html>%s<font color='red'>%s</font></html>", 
        statusLabel.getText(), message));
```